# Python/Numpy/OpenCV merging 2 images by showing one next to the other separated by a diagonal line

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

There are 2 images, need to combine them using python/numpy/OpenCV to show the final image, where the left half is from the first image and the right half is from the second image.

The final image should be divided by a white diagonal line of the specified width up to 5 pixels, where the diagonal is specified by a specific angle, and which side is closer to the left and right.

Example:
[Example merging 2 images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ivm4.jpg)

Comment: you should show that [you attempted to solve this yourself](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Answer (score 3):

Here's how i would do it:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from skimage.transform import rescale
import numpy as np

img0 = plt.imread('example01.jpeg')
img1 = plt.imread('example02.jpeg')
scale = img1.shape[0]/img0.shape[0]
img0_rescaled = (rescale(img0, [scale, scale, 1])[:, :img1.shape[1], :]*255).astype(np.uint8)

combined = np.ones_like(img1)*255
angle = -np.pi/2.5
lower_intersection = 0.5
line_width = 50

y, x, _ = img1.shape

yy, xx = np.mgrid[:y, :x]
img0_positions = (xx-lower_intersection*x)*np.tan(angle)-line_width//2>(yy-y)
img1_positions = (xx-lower_intersection*x)*np.tan(angle)+line_width//2<(yy-y)

combined[img0_positions] = img0_rescaled[img0_positions]
combined[img1_positions] = img1[img1_positions]
```

[output example](https://ibb.co/1GhMVJx)